# XAMPP MYSQL shutdown and how to recover transfered files

Tags: mysql, xampp, innodb

I have a database called "znacky". I am using XAMPP. One time, MYSQL shutdown unexpectedly, and out of ignorance I go to `xampp/mysql/data` folder and copied my database `znacky` folder then uninstalled my xampp (without copying the `ib_logfiles` and `ibdata`).

I got all these data from my `znacky` folder:

- admin FRM file
- admin IBD file
- table1 FRM file
- table1 IBD file
- db.opt OPT file
- FTS_0000000000000001f_BEING_DELETED IBD file
- FTS_0000000000000001f_BEING_DELETED_CACHE IBD file
- FTS_0000000000000001f_CONFIG IBD file
- FTS_0000000000000001f_DELETED IBD file
- FTS_0000000000000001f_DELETED_CACHE IBD file

I reinstalled xampp and copy-pasted the `znacky` folder to the new `xampp/mysql/data` folder. I still have the MySQL unexpected shutdown error.

Can I still recover all the data I inserted to my data tables of my database?

This is the error log in xampp's mysql:

```
2015-03-09 14:56:54 4692 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-03-09 14:56:54 1fa4 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2015-03-09 14:56:54 4692 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-03-09 14:56:54 4692 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-03-09 14:56:54 4692 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2015-03-09 14:56:54 4692 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-03-09 14:56:54 4692 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-03-09 14:56:54 4692 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2015-03-09 14:56:54 4692 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-03-09 14:56:55 4692 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-03-09 14:56:58 4692 [Warning] InnoDB: Resizing redo log from 2*3072 to 2*320 pages, LSN=1625987
2015-03-09 14:56:58 4692 [Warning] InnoDB: Starting to delete and rewrite log files.
2015-03-09 14:56:58 4692 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file D:\Application\mysql\data\ib_logfile101 size to 5 MB
2015-03-09 14:56:59 4692 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file D:\Application\mysql\data\ib_logfile1 size to 5 MB
2015-03-09 14:56:59 4692 [Note] InnoDB: Renaming log file D:\Application\mysql\data\ib_logfile101 to D:\Application\mysql\data\ib_logfile0
2015-03-09 14:56:59 4692 [Warning] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=1625987
2015-03-09 14:56:59 4692 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2015-03-09 14:57:00 4692 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-03-09 14:57:00 4692 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.16 started; log sequence number 1625987
2015-03-09 14:57:03 4692 [Warning] No existing UUID has been found, so we assume that this is the first time that this server has been started. Generating a new UUID: 7e0f7298-c629-11e4-945f-c454448d2ab8.
2015-03-09 14:57:04 4692 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2015-03-09 14:57:04 4692 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2015-03-09 14:57:04 4692 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2015-03-09 14:57:04 4692 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2015-03-09 15:03:15 6480 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-03-09 15:03:17 15e4 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2015-03-09 15:03:17 6480 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-03-09 15:03:17 6480 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-03-09 15:03:17 6480 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2015-03-09 15:03:17 6480 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-03-09 15:03:17 6480 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-03-09 15:03:17 6480 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2015-03-09 15:03:17 6480 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-03-09 15:03:18 6480 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-03-09 15:03:18 6480 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 1625987 and 1625987 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 1626134 in the ib_logfiles!
```

And also these files came out of nowhere from my `znacky` folder:

- FTS_0000000000000001f_BEING_DELETED IBD file,
- FTS_0000000000000001f_BEING_DELETED_CACHE IBD file,
- FTS_0000000000000001f_CONFIG IBD file,
- FTS_0000000000000001f_DELETED IBD file,
- FTS_0000000000000001f_DELETED_CACHE IBD file

Comment: Did you have a set of .ibd files with names matching your tables?  Do you have the `CREATE TABLEs`?  If so, there _might_ be hope; rephrase the question to "how to recover data from .ibd without ibdata1".  If not, cry.

Comment: yes i have the .ibd files and .frm files, what i dont have is the create tables, and the ibdata1. What would be the first step i'd do?

Comment: @RickJames do you have some ideas to help me my friend?

Comment: I don't have the specifics, so search around.  There is some way to recover a table if you can recreate the table (empty) and you have the .ibd.  The problem involves somehow telling ibdata1 about it.